# stream.write This expression is not callable

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nodejs-stream

I am trying to a write a function that takes either writeable stream (createWriteStream) or process.stdout/.stderr but typescript keeps throwing this error.
Error goes away when I do conditional type check.

```
import { createWriteStream, WriteStream } from 'fs'

const writehello = (stream: NodeJS.WriteStream & { fd: 1 } | WriteStream) => stream.write('hello\n') // error

writehello(process.stdout)
writehello(createWriteStream('/tmp/al.txt'))
```

Error message at line 3

```
error TS2349: This expression is not callable.
  Each member of the union type '{ (buffer: string | Uint8Array, cb?: ((err?: Error | undefined) => void) | undefined): boolean; (str: string | Uint8Array, encoding?: BufferEncoding | undefined, cb?: ((err?:
Error | undefined) => void) | undefined): boolean; } | { ...; }' has signatures, but none of those signatures are compatible with each other.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `NodeJS.WriteStream` and `WriteStream` overload the `write()` method, but they use different signatures, resulting in the error you are seeing.

Instead of defining the union type between these two types, you can define the type of the `stream` parameter using `Writable`, that is extended by both:

```
import { createWriteStream } from 'fs'
import { Writable } from 'stream'

const writehello = (stream: Writable) => stream.write('hello\n')

writehello(process.stdout)
writehello(createWriteStream('/tmp/al.txt'))
```